# Como copiar um arquivo .txt que atualiza o nome diariamente - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso copiar um arquivo TXT diariamente de uma pasta para outra, porém o arquivo é renomeado de acordo com a data, o final após o "_"
sempre altera com o valor da data.

Ex: `_20181205.txt`, `_20181206.txt`, `_20190101.txt`.

Abaixo está o código onde parei.

```
shutil.copy('/8.Relatórios/03. SAM/01_TemposMédios_20181205.txt','C:/Users/br0151338587/Desktop/laboratorioPython')
```

Alguém saberia como faço para resolver essa questão?

*Obs: a 1º url é de uma pasta em rede, então apaguei o inicio para

facilitar a leitura.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você utilizar o método [`date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) do módulo `datetime` para pegar a data atual e usar [as opções de formatação de data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) para criar corretamente o nome do arquivo que você deseja. Por exemplo:

```
from datetime import date

hoje = date.today()
arquivo = f"01_TemposMédios_{hoje:%Y%m%d}.txt"

print(arquivo)  # '01_TemposMédios_20191205.txt'
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-348020-6333) com o código funcionando</sup>

No exemplo acima estou utilizando interpolação de strings com [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) implementada no Python 3.6+), mas você pode usar [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) se preferir.

```
arquivo = "01_TemposMédios_{0:%Y%m%d}.txt".format(hoje)
```

Você pode usar o [pyformat.org](https://pyformat.info/#datetime) com um *cheatsheet* para formatações em python.

---

Com as informações acima você já tem ferramentas suficientes para resolver seu problema. Você vai ter um código parecido com isso:

```
from shutil import copy
from datetime import date

hoje = date.today()
arquivo_origem = f"/8.Relatórios/03. SAM/01_TemposMédios_{hoje:%Y%m%d}.txt"
arquivo_destino = "C:/Users/br0151338587/Desktop/laboratorioPython"

copy(arquivo_origem, arquivo_destino)
```